# How to insert co-ordinates via parameterized query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a parameterized query in PHP and was wondering how to execute an `INSERT` query with `FLOAT(10,6)` datatype.

The query goes something like:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (lat, lng) VALUES(?, ?)");
```

[According to PHP's specification of bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), it only accepts integer, string, double, and blob values.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can treat it as double.

Comment: What if latitude is negative?

Comment: double can be negative, isn't it ?

Comment: @Raptor Yup it can. Let me try and pass it as a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dd as double

```
$stmt->bind_param("dd", $lat, $lng);
```